# How to fit unordered list inside of parent span, mine skips to the next line instead of flowing downward

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, alignment

I am writing this code and I want to include 3 buttons under the photo of the recipe as icons, such as a time icon and then the time it takes to make it to the right of the icon. However, the list does not go under the card, it instead moves to a new line.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../stylesheets/recipes.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/recipes.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="btn">
            <a href="../index.html">
                <button id="logobtn">
                    <img src="../images/logo.png" class="logo" alt="Chef logo">
                </button>
            </a>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="restaurants.html">Restaurants</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="current">Recipes</a></li>
                <li><a href="requests.html">Requests</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <h1> Recipes </h1>
    <div class="cards">
        <a class="card" href="#">
            <span class="card-header">
                <img src="../images/benedict.jpg" class="cardpic">
                <span class="card-title">
                    <h3>Eggs Benedict</h3>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="cardsummary">
                <p> Love it <br><br><br></p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-adn"></i></a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-android"></i></a> </li>   
                        <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-apple"></i></a> </li>
                    </ul>
            </span>
        </a>

        <a class="card" href="#">
            <span class="card-header">
                <img src="../images/eclair.jpg" class="cardpic">
                <span class="card-title">
                    <h3>Chocolate Eclairs</h3>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="card-summary">
                Each card is created from an &lt;a&gt; tag so the whole card is linked.
                <ul class="list-inline"> 
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-adn"></i></a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-android"></i></a> </li>   
                        <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-apple"></i></a> </li>
                    </ul>
            </span> 

        </a>
        <a class="card" href="#">
            <span class="card-header">
                <img src="../images/penne.jpg" class="cardpic">
                <span class="card-title">
                    <h3>Penne alla Vodka</h3>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="card-summary">
                Each card is created from an &lt;a&gt; tag so the whole card is linked.
            </span>
        </a>
        <a class="card" href="#">
            <span class="card-header">
                <img src="../images/rissoto.jpg" class="cardpic">
                <span class="card-title">
                    <h3>Chocolate Eclairs</h3>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="card-summary">
                Each card is created from an &lt;a&gt; tag so the whole card is linked.
            </span>
        </a>
        <a class="card" href="#">
            <span class="card-header">
                <img src="../images/rissoto.jpg" class="cardpic">
                <span class="card-title">
                    <h3>Chocolate Eclairs</h3>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="card-summary">
                Each card is created from an &lt;a&gt; tag so the whole card is linked.
            </span>
        </a>
        <a class="card" href="#">
            <span class="card-header">
                <img src="../images/rissoto.jpg" class="cardpic">
                <span class="card-title">
                    <h3>Chocolate Eclairs</h3>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="card-summary">
                Each card is created from an &lt;a&gt; tag so the whole card is linked.
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The card summary with text is displayed properly, under the photo, but anytime I place the list inside of that div it takes on its own property and display elements, instead of wrapping with the parent container.

I am tying to essentially add stylized icons under EACH card as a summary header, and then I will have the text below all 3 of the icons present in every card, but the list of icons just keeps moving onto the next line, and I truly can't figure it out.

CSS:

```
body { 
  font-family: oswald;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff4ea;
}
.background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li a:hover {
    color: #E49273;
}
span:hover {
    color: #E49273;
}

header {
    background: #fff4ea;
    width: 100%;
    height: 76px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    z-index: 100;
}
.btn {
    -webkit-transition all: 700ms ease;
    transition all: 700ms ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#logobtn {
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;    
    float: left;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 104px;
}

.logo{
    width: 100px;
    height: 104px;
}

nav {
    float: right;
    padding: 20px;  
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;

}

.current {
    color: #A37A74;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    color: #7180AC;
    font-size: 5em;
    line-height: 1.15em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.15em;
}

p {
    line-height: 1.45em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.skew-forward {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 10% 100%;
    transform-origin: 10% 100%;
}
.skew-forward:hover {
    -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg);
    transform: skew(-10deg);
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 685px) {

    header {
        position: absolute;
    }

    nav ul, nav:active ul { 
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 20px;
        right: 0px;
        top: 75px;
        width: 50%;
    }

    nav li {
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px 0px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    nav:hover ul {
        display: block;
    }

  a:hover {
    color: yellow;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 790px) {
  div.btn {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  h1 {
    float: none;
    display: none;
    font-size: 3em;
    }
    .card {
        margin-top: 15%;
    }
}



@import "compass";
@import "breakpoint";

/*//Todo clean up some crappy code
*/
.cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 10%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card {
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 5%; 
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    color: #363636;
}
.cardpic {
    position: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%; // stop images from breaking out of their bounding boxes.
}

    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        width: 100%;
    }

    @include box-shadow(rgba(black, 0.19) 0 0 8px 0);
    @include border-radius(4px);
    @include breakpoint(700px, $no-query: true) {
/*  //switch to 2 columns
*/      max-width: 320px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        &:nth-child(even) {
            margin-right: 0;
        }
    }
    /*@include breakpoint(980px, $no-query: true) {
    //switch to 3 columns
        &:nth-child(even) {
            margin-right: 20px;
        }
        &:nth-child(3n) {
            margin-right: 0;
        }
    }*/
    span {
        display: block;
    }
    .card-summary {
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 5%;
    }
    .cardsummary {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 5%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    }

    .card-header {
        position: inherit;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-blend-mode: overlay;
        border-radius(4px 4px 0 0);
        max-width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0%;

    }
    .card-title {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.60);
        padding: 3.5% 0 3.5% 0;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0.5%;
        width: 100%;
    }
        h3 {
            font-size: 1.2em;
            line-height: 1.2;
            padding: 0 3.5%;
            margin: 0;
        }


.icon-zoom{
    position: inherit;

}

ul {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
/*---- Genral classes end -------*/

/*Change icons size here*/
.social-icons .fa {
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
/*Change icons circle size and color here*/
.social-icons .fa {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.social-icons.icon-circle .fa{ 
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.social-icons.icon-rounded .fa{
    border-radius:5px;
}
.social-icons.icon-flat .fa{
    border-radius: 0;
}

.social-icons .fa:hover, .social-icons .fa:active {
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #333;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #333;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #333; 
}
.social-icons.icon-zoom .fa:hover, .social-icons.icon-zoom .fa:active { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1); 
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#logobtn").hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("skew-forward").toggleClass("blur");
    }); 
    $("a[href='#']").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `<a>` in `<a>`. If you remove one `<a>` for example from all `<ul>` lists: 
`<li><i class="fa fa-adn"></i></li>` the `<ul>` element will be correctly interpreted by the browser.

To have `<ul><li>` elements in one line you can use for example `"display: flex; justify-content: center"` on `<ul>` or `"float: left;"` on `<ul><li>` elements.

To check markup validity you can use also https://validator.w3.org